# Flags to compile & time to compile

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization

On my `makefile` I've got this:

> CC    = g++
>
> CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wunused -g -ggdb

And my project takes about 22 seconds to compile on my machine (Core2, 3 GB ram - it takes about 1 minute in my netbook...), and it's not even that big (let's say about 50 classes.)

Which of the above compiling flags may be the cause of this?
OR
How could I accelerate compiling time?

Comment: Surely it's occurred to you to jus remove them individually and see what happens....

Comment: C++ is hard to compile.  Are you using `make`'s `-j` flag?

Comment: On a side note: [you better be thankful it takes long.](http://xkcd.com/303/)

Comment: How big is the resulting executable? It takes time to write to disk. As a result, `-g -ggdb` can add time, but you want that if you're debugging.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, 2 MB.

Answer (score 0):

None of those compiler flags will significantly affect compile time. The only ones that generally do are optimization flags, and you aren't using any of those.

Precompiling some or all of your headers may help compile times. Or not, depending on what your code looks like.